# word document in opencv

Tags: opencv, ms-word

I need to access a word document with an image and then process that image for patterns. Is there a way to read a word document and store it as IplImage in opencv?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689099/document-image-processing/8073782#8073782) might give you some ideas of what needs to be done to accomplish that task.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the Word document to Powerpoint where you can save it as a jpeg image.
That image can be loaded in Opencv as IplImage.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV cannot read Word files (which version BTW?).

If this is a one-time operation, you can always open the file in Word, set the view size (zoom) to 100%, use print-screen to capture the image to the clipboard, and paste it into any image editing program (IrfanView, Photoshop, MSPaint) for proper cropping. Then save your image as an image file (e.g. PNG, BMP, JPG) and process it using OpenCV.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV cannot read Word files.

If you do not want a save-jpg-to-a-file-option, you could read up on the file format of a Word file, and open it in your program (using fopen or something) and read each byte of it.